# Junit: testing whether a method do return a byte array

Tags: java, testing, junit

Let's say I have a method similar to the following:

```
public byte[] getByteArrayOutOfIt(Long Id)
{
Paper p = paper.getPaper(Id);
return convertPaperToByteArray(p); 
}
```

Any idea how to actually JUnit test whether it returns a byte[]?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This method can't return anything other than a byte array or null. Do you want to test that it doesn't return null?

Comment: @JBNizet yhea I thought about assertNotNull method.. however wantend to now if there was something more precise like if all the bytes have been properly returned. I think you right though, maybe just assertNotNull should do the trick

Comment: Your test should assert that this method returns the `byte[]` you expect, not just that it doesn't return `null`